# Javascript : how to insert tags around a text selection?

Tags: javascript, contenteditable

I want to create a little WYSIWYG HTML text editor with a contenteditable div.

For that, I use window.getSelection() to retrieve the selected text, and when I click in a button (button bold), I execute a function to add bold tags around the selected text.

But I don't have any idea about the javascript code (without JQuery) to add bold tags.

Here my code :

```
<input type="button" value="B" style="font-weight:bold;" onclick='add_tags("b");'>

<div id="container_contenteditable" class="container_contenteditable" contenteditable></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function add_tags(tags)
{
    container_contenteditable = document.getElementById("container_contenteditable");

    //Retrieve the selected text :
    sel = window.getSelection();
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually simpler than you might think:

```js
function add_tags(tags)
{
    document.execCommand('bold');
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="B" style="font-weight:bold;" onclick='add_tags("b");'>

<div class="container_contenteditable" contenteditable style="border:1px solid; margin: 10px 0; height: 100px;"></div>
```

Comment: This is indeed the correct method. But writing your own editor is something close to a nightmare...Every browser has his own implementations, IE uses `<strong>` instead of `<b>` as example. Some browsers add random attributes.
 And every browser has it's own idea about line breaks, `<div>`, `<p>`, `<br />` etc... I tried writing my own editor once but gave up in the end so many things that need to be done to get it working exactly the same crossbrowser.

Comment: @Daniel thank you a lot, it's the best solution. If I want to add ul tag and display the first point of a <li>, How can I do that ?

Comment: @totoaussi, I think you can do that using document.execCommand('insertOrderedList'). Here are the list of commands you could use it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand

Answer (score 3):

Writing your own editor is not that nightmare-ish - but it does require a lot of time, attention to detail and learning.

When I wrote mine I ended up converting all styling to spans - in the end it's easier and gives a consistency across browsers.

So with spans, you replace the current selection with (eg:) `<span style="font-weight:bold">your selected text</span>`

Works a treat...

Comment: And to add <ul> tag and display the 1rst <li> point, how can you do that ?

Comment: Hang on! - I thought we were talking about replacing a selection - adding a new list is to add a new block element, so it should be inserted before or after the relevant element. You need document.createElement("UL"); then  Elm.parentNode.insertBefore() - look up the details - then you can add the first LI element by setting the new UL element's innerHTML. (Other variations are available).

Answer (score 2):

Set "container_contenteditable" as id attribute, since you are using getElementById.

You can replace the selected text with replace function. Here is the fix.

```js
function add_tags(tags)
{
    var container_contenteditable = document.getElementById("container_contenteditable");

    //Retrieve the selected text :
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var text = container_contenteditable.innerHTML;
  container_contenteditable.innerHTML = text.replace(sel, '<b>'+sel+'</b>');
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="B" style="font-weight:bold;" onclick='add_tags("b");'>

<div id="container_contenteditable" contenteditable>Make the name siva to bold</div>
```

Comment: Replacing text is a BAD idea, if there is a text selection that has partial bold text the html ends up with unnecessary `<b>` tags inside `<b>` tags.

Comment: Bad idea, What if your content was: 'Make the name siva to bold siva siva', and you select last 'siva' ?

Answer (score 1):

You could just wrap `<b>`-tags around the selection:

Furthermore, your HTML should look like this:

```
<input type="button" value="B" style="font-weight:bold;" onclick='add_tags("b");'>

<div id="container_contenteditable" contenteditable>TestTextTest</div>
```

And the JavaScript:

```
    function add_tags(tags) {
  container_contenteditable = document.getElementById("container_contenteditable");
  //Retrieve the selected text :
  sel = window.getSelection();
  //Check if selection does contain something
  if (sel != "") {
    //set the innerHTML of container_contenteditable
    //we're just wrapping a <b>-tag around the selected text
    container_contenteditable.innerHTML = "<b>" + sel + "</b>";
  } else {
    //if the selected text was blank
    alert("Nothing selected.");
  }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work for text selection inside a multi-line text.

Comment: Also see my comment @siva, this is a bad idea and not recommended. So there are 2 options, use the built in execcommand and keep writing js till infiniti to make it work the same crossbrowser or write your own implementation for the execcommand and also write your own implementations for all other user interaction like line breaks. I decided for option 3: use an existing plugin, let the others do the work...